# Deploy Modules from Parent POM - Java Maven

Tags: java, maven, deployment, pom.xml, nexus

I have a project with a parent POM that contents some modules. One of these modules is a project with a lot of dependencies subprojects (about 50 projects) Actually its compile without errors but I want to deploy all jars to a Nexus repository from parent POM, optimizing the solution, avoiding configuring each child's POM or module with Nexus and Maven plugins properties.
it's possible?

This is the parent POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>Proyecto_project</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>      
    <module>./Proyecto-web-services</module>
    <module>./ValidarSessionProyectoProxy</module>
    <module>./ValidarSessionProyecto</module>
    <module>./promociones</module>
     <module>./Proyecto</module>
</modules>  

<dependencies>     
        <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>         
 </dependencies>

   <build>
    <plugins>
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>                
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.8</version>
       <executions>
          <execution>
             <id>default-deploy</id>
             <phase>deploy</phase>
             <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
             </goals>
          </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
          <serverId>nexus-snapshots</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-Proyecto-releases</nexusUrl>
          <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

 <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
          <url>http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-Proyecto-releases</url>
    </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
              <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
              <url>http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-Proyecto-releases</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Result:

```
Uploading: http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-PROYECTO-releases/com/company/PROYECTO_project/1/PROYECTO_project-1.pom
Uploaded: http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-PROYECTO-releases/com/company/PROYECTO_project/1/PROYECTO_project-1.pom (2 KB at 6.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-PROYECTO-releases/com/company/PROYECTO_project/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-PROYECTO-releases/com/company/PROYECTO_project/maven-metadata.xml (296 B at 4.1 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-PROYECTO-releases/com/company/PROYECTO_project/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: http://1.1.1.1:80/repository/mvn-PROYECTO-releases/com/company/PROYECTO_project/maven-metadata.xml (296 B at 2.5 KB/sec)
[INFO]  * Bulk deploy of locally gathered snapshot artifacts finished.
[INFO] Remote deploy finished with success.
```

but the other JARs are not deployed in nexus:

```
[INFO] Proyecto_jar1........ .................. SUCCESS [  6.589 s]
[INFO] Proyecto_jar2 .......................... SUCCESS [  0.378 s]
[INFO] Proyecto_jar3.......... ................ SUCCESS [  0.523 s]
[INFO] Proyecto_jar4.. ........................ SUCCESS [  0.435 s]
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why not just put the configuration into the parent POM?

Comment: I did it, but only poms of last project is deployed on nexus. I want to deploy all jar dependencies compiled in the first modules.

Comment: I guess you have set the `skip` option to `true` for the `maven-deploy-plugin` as you did it in the parent project.

Comment: No , i didn't . I will try with this option.